# Is it slower to pass a composite type representing a table to a function then the individual arguments?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, postgresql-performance, functions, composite-types

Let's say you want to create a function

```
CREATE FUNCTION f(a,b,c,x,y,z) FROM t;
```

Is it any slower to restructure the function such that this works,

```
CREATE FUNCTION f(t) FROM t;
```

Answer (score 1):

## No the overhead is not different.

In order to benchmark this I create a table with ten million rows.

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo(a,b,c,x,y,z) AS
SELECT x, x%2, x%3, x%4, x%5, x%6
FROM generate_series(1,1E7) AS gs(x);
```

Then I create two functions

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION fn_composite(t foo)
RETURNS int
AS $$
  SELECT t.a + t.b + t.c + t.x + t.y + t.z;
$$
LANGUAGE SQL
IMMUTABLE;

CREATE FUNCTION fn_plain(a numeric,b numeric,c numeric,x numeric,y numeric,z numeric)
RETURNS int
AS $$
  SELECT a + b + c + x + y + z;
$$
LANGUAGE SQL
IMMUTABLE;
```

Then I ran

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT fn_composite(foo) FROM foo;
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT fn_plain(a,b,c,x,y,z) FROM foo;
```

In my experience, both of these produced the roughly the same timings. Now let's try it with fewer columns needed though, maybe the composite one has a higher overhead and sends more data then needed.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION fn_composite(t foo)
RETURNS int
AS $$
  SELECT t.a
$$
LANGUAGE SQL
IMMUTABLE;

CREATE FUNCTION fn_plain(a numeric)
RETURNS int
AS $$
  SELECT a
$$
LANGUAGE SQL
IMMUTABLE;
```

Benchmarking the above with

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT fn_composite(foo) FROM foo;
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT fn_plain(a) FROM foo;
```

And again the timings were roughly the same. Other things I tried,

- Adding more intergers,
- Adding text columns `REPEAT('foobar', 100)`